# Trichromelibrary was suddenly downloading from Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, android-10

From nowhere, my friend got a notification that `com.google.android.trichromelibrary` was downloading together with a progress bar.

[image: screenshot]

Why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [Shared Libraries on Android](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/android_native_libraries.md) which explains
native code in Chrome on Android

> - Android L & M need ChromeModernPublic.aab
> - Android N, O & P need MonochromePublic.aab
> - **Android Q** needs TrichromeChrome.aab + **TrichromeLibrary**.apk

(Emphasis added)

Further down the page it explains what these packages do (in developer speak). So, it's perfectly safe and legit, as it is a part of Android Chrome - nothing to be worried about.

**Edit:** From [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/10/24/android-10-no-longer-uses-chrome-app-to-render-pages-inside-apps/)

> ... Chrome no longer appeared an option in the WebView picker (found in Android's Developer Options). A Google engineer explained that Android 10 uses a new implementation called 'Trichrome':

> > "Chrome is no longer used as a WebView implementation in Q+. We've moved to a new model for sharing common code between Chrome and WebView (called "Trichrome") which gives the same benefits of reduced download and install size while having fewer weird special cases and bugs."

Comment: Last couple months I couldn't update Chrome and Android System WebView. Tried today and again updates couldn't be done, but this `trichromelibrary` was installed instead and then WebView update was finally triggered so I assume the purpose of this package is to fix these updates

Comment: Related for [cleaning old Trichrome libraries](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242721/131553) // You can use [Trichrome Squoosh Magisk module](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Alt-Repo/trichromelibrary-squoosh)