# com.google.android.trichromelibrary causes many Android apps to crash

Tags: chrome-for-android, crash-reports

Recently, apps that are fine an hour ago now crash when I open them. The crash report message seems to be caused by a null pointer exception (NPE) in `com.google.android.trichromelibrary`.

Apps affected for me:

- Gmail
- Dashlane

Is it just me, or is there actually something wrong with the library? How can I fix these affected apps?

Crash report:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/polaris/polaris:10/QKQ1.190828.002/20.9.4:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: ...
pid: ..., tid: ..., name: com.dashlane >>> com.dashlane <<<
uid: ...
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    
    ...

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000038621f0 /data/app/
com.google.android.trichromelibrary 438909034-YaxP9ttrIDcQBfleP5vm7Q==/base.apk!
libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x646000) (BuildId: ... )
```

<sup>(click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcKCO.jpg) for the screenshot of the bug report)</sup>

Comment: This library is an [integral part](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228214/131553) of Chrome and therefore shouldn't be the cause. However try uninstalling updates to Chrome and web view to see if crashes stop //If they don't the problem could be with those apps like Gmail and uninstall their updates to cleck

Comment: Follow-up by Google regarding the issue: [Google explains why WebView crashed Android apps last month and upcoming mitigations](https://9to5google.com/2021/04/20/android-webview-crash-fix/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was a WebView issue and it has been fixed as mentioned here:

https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&sid=1&iid=aa75515d184a2423be444d676b7ebf45

> Updating Android System WebView and Google Chrome via Google Play
> should now resolve the issue for all users.
>
> 1. Navigate to Play Store app
> 2. Search for Android System WebView (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview)
> 3. Select the "Update" option
> 4. Repeat these steps for Google Chrome (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome)
>
> For more information about updating Android apps please see:
> https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412

Comment: This assumes you can get WebView to update itself. I've tried several times and it just spins and says it's "pending" :( I "uninstalled" it (updates, that it) and all my crashing apps went back to working fine, but it still won't update itself. Maybe tomorrow...

Comment: @FreeMan you can sideload an update for an app. Download the newest apk (using [Raccoon](https://raccoon.onyxbits.de/downloads/) or APKMirror.com) and install it. That's it. If the APK carries the same signature the installed app it would install (confirming that the downloaded apk is indeed genuine and not compromised by a third-party), otherwise, the installation would fail.

Comment: This answer assume the user has registered an account with Google. It would be better to provide instructions on how to get the APK from public sources.

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading "Android System WebView" (which seems to be related to the Trichrome Library) solved this problem on my phone.