# My Newly Installled Games Keep Crashing

Tags: crashes, google-play-games

I have downloaded 3 new games: Idle Slayer, Shadow Hunter and Archero. They are all small games that don't require that much space or graphic processing. I was able to play them for 3 days with no issues whatsoever but out of nowhere they started to crash. I open them, it shows the title screen for a second and it closes entirely on it's own. This problem doesn't happen with any other games or apps I previously had installed. I have a Huawei Mate 20 Lite, it has 25,40 GB of free space out of 64 GB and 4 GB of RAM. I clean up space weekly. I cleared the caches of all the previously mentioned games and it still kept happenning. So I uninstalled Archero and Idle Slayer because I knew I had them connected to Google Games so I wouldn't lose progress. When I reinstalled them they worked but when I closed them and tried to open them up again, they had the same problem of crashing and it's been that way ever since. My phone's not old, it's been 1 and a half years since I've bought it and I haven't installed from nor visited sketchy websites. My software is up to date and it's not a problem of internet, I've checked that angle too. Can someone please shed light on what I can do to resolve this issue? I quite enjoy these games and I worry it'll affect future installments to my phone. Thank you from advance.

Comment: Yesterday Google pushed a defect Chrome/WebView update which causes all apps to crash that are trying to display web pages inside the app. See this question for a resolution [Android com.google.android.trichromelibrary causes other apps to crash](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234830/android-com-google-android-trichromelibrary-causes-other-apps-to-crash)

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Updating the Android System WebView from the Google Play Store solved it. I owe you one.