# Phone apps crashing

Tags: usb-mass-storage, lagging

My apps won't start up if they do its not long enough to use them. Either they just close as soon as i open them or a message reading (app name) has stopped responding and its even apps that I haven't opened like my Google play will pop up saying it has stopped. I'm not sure what to do I've shutoff and restarted my phone I've uninstalled and reinstalled my apps anf it works for a minute but then it's right back to crashing.  I can't even use google to search it won't allow me to type more than 1 letter and it freezes then closes the app...

Comment: Recently there was a buggy update from Chrome that affected apps with WebView. However, it's not clear if the issue you're facing is the same or not. Consider also checking [this Q&A](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234830/44325).

Comment: If the mentioned solution fails to work, ping me. I would reopen your question.