# Can I delete old trichrome library under /data/app?

Tags: chrome-for-android, debloat, trichrome

I have around 50 trichrome library folders in `/data/app` using around 3 gb.

What varies is the alphanumeric string after the package name denoting version:
`com.google.android.trichromelibrary_410408383-VgzblS0EY8swXcjTqN6reQ==`

Can I delete all but most recent to clean my system and regain some space?

Or is it like WinSxS folder in Windows where all revisions of the same dll are stored for different programs to use?

###UPDATE AUGUST 2022###

Latest Trichrome updates (I'm now on 511.209.733) seem to take care of old versions disinstalling them and leaving only the latest, no more need to manually delete in `/data/app` and `/data/data`

Comment: +1, After posting comment, checked on my phone to discover the same. The same question has been asked on [Google support forums](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/41668937/%E5%85%B3%E4%BA%8E%E6%95%B0%E6%8D%AE-%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%8F%E4%B8%8B%E7%9A%84%E5%A4%9A%E4%B8%AAcom-google-android-trichromelibrary?hl=en) though the answer lacks details as to why so many versions

Comment: [Related.......](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228214/131553)

Comment: Uninstall all versions of `trichrome` library by typing `pm uninstall com.google.android.trichromelibrary_410408383` (replace the ending version part). Then update Chrome/WebView from Play Store. // Even simpler: stop using Google products as much as possible.

Comment: @beeshyams every new version of `trichrome` library is installed as a separate package. So uninstall them specifically, not Chrome/WebView. Update the latter both if they break due to missing library.

Comment: I get `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]` when trying to `pm uninstall`

Comment: even adding `--user 0` i get `NOT INSTALLED FOR THIS USER`

Comment: Is this a problem on rooted phones only? Do the different versions of trichrome appear in the list of `pm list packages -f` (or is there another way to check existence of such libraries on unrooted phones)?

Comment: using `pm list libraries` you can see one trichrome entry but no more details afaik

Comment: @JuTutt Yep, you do not see build number that is needed for uninstall. But you can look it up on apkcombo using Es Explorer that shows build number. See: https://github.com/entr0pia/trichromelibrary-squoosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted all but last using `rm -r com.google.android.trichromelibrary_41*`(then 42, 43, 44...) in `/data/app/`, `/data/data/`, `/data/user_de/0/`, `/data/misc/profiles`, `/data/system/package_cache`, working fine, 3 gb freed.

Should be safe to issue the `rm` command of above straight in `/data` just for convenience.

Then you should purge your `/data/system/packages.xml` file from orphaned entries as explained here: [Purge /data/system/packages.xml from manually deleted packages](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242972/purge-data-system-packages-xml-from-manually-deleted-packages)

Comment: +1, confirm it works on Android 12 too, though I found them in first & third location only. Had to update Chrome and web view to get them working (I had unistalled updates before deletion)

Comment: do you think is it possible to purge old versions on a not rooted device?

Comment: Unlikely IMO. Especially with scoped storage since Android 10. Even on earlier versions one can't access `/data/data` without root and if Chrome is a system app it's out of bounds

Comment: of course doing this brutal `rm` delete thing instead of a more graceful `pm uninstall` leaves all of the old Trichrome versions entries as leftover in `/data/system/packages.xml`. Is there a way to purge it automatically? Reboot doesn't clean it.

Comment: On a rooted phone, one can use [Trichrome Squoosh Magisk module](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Alt-Repo/trichromelibrary-squoosh)