# com.google.android.trichromelibrary - An app that gets installs multiple times .....what's the point?

Tags: adb, storage, google-play-services, webview, trichrome

As  I understand `com.google.android.trichromelibrary` is supposed to be a  `webview` replacement in `android 10+`

```
 find /data/app -type d   -iname "*trichrome*" -exec du -hs  {} \;
70M     /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_475808733-hbwaY4KXRVEdoKq10mzzfQ==
71M     /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484407333-96Dwrx11cIuvXstExOmMTA==
72M     /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary.dev_495100733-Znh6eO5SOBu_ORYXeXI2zw==
71M     /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408833-7teK0Hyij0I9yq5l070LmQ==
```

After uninstall

```
# find /data/app -type d   -iname "*trichrome*" -exec ls -ald  {>
drwxrwxr-x 4 system system 3488 2022-03-23 18:10 /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484407333-96Dwrx11cIuvXstExOmMTA==
drwxrwxr-x 4 system system 3488 2022-03-31 00:38 /data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484408833-7teK0Hyij0I9yq5l070LmQ==
```

4 instances ? for the same app. Why ? I manged to remove 2 of them  using `pm uninstall` so as to keep just 1 -  but  I get the below error, after being stuck with 2 instances remaining instead of 1.

```
pm uninstall com.google.android.trichromelibrary_484407333                         <
Failure [DELETE_FAILED_USED_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

**My Questions**
-- Why 4 instances of the same app. Is it by design ?  How do I know which app tried to install the additional instance of  `trichrome library` and why did it do so when 1 exists 
-- This happened in the past too. How do I ***prevent recurrence.*** So I dont have to clean up everytime.
-- Other than brute  `rm -rf` on the un-wanted folder anyway I can uninstall the unwanted instance

Comment: Related: [Multiple numbered copies of com.google.android.gms inside /data/app using up all the space on a device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242921/44325), [Can I delete old trichrome library under /data/app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242721/44325). As of current, without knowing how Play Store/Services works, it's just assumed that a clean-up code to remove old, unused instances is inefficient/does not exist.

Comment: I am aware of the above. That's  the purpose of the Q . *Why ?* the x'ple instances and *How* to prevent them

Comment: https://github.com/Undefined-User/TrichromeLibrary_Remover

Comment: I don't understand anything about webview but my guess is that is unique profile for each app that uses webview (I only have two)? edit: just deleted it, now my chrome browser app data and macrodroid wigdet is gone - obviously these apps created trichrome data then..