# Why do I have multiple Google Play Services and Google Play Service caches running on my device, and how do I get rid of them?

Tags: samsung, google-play-services, cache

I have a Samsung Galaxy A54 5G (SM-A546U) that has been severely compromised. I have sometimes 3 or 4 Google Play Services and 3 to 4 Google Play Service system caches running at any given time.

How do I get rid of the extras?

Things I've tried:

1. Clearing the data and cache in the Settings app
2. Stopping the app
3. Uninstall and reinstall the app
4. Factory reset the device

More times than I can count, and in less than 1 minute, there are still multiple Google Play Services and Google Play Service system caches running, and the multiples are not a part of the Samsung Secure Folder.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. I can send screenshots and any other evidence to help.

Comment: If you are unlucky and Google services crash this can repeat multiple times. That can but doesn't have to be an indicator for a compromised system. By performing a factory reset you uninstall all installed updates also for Google services and this can be one of your problems. You can try to manually install a newer version of those services that crash.

Comment: The device is most definitely compromised, this is the 6 th device that has had the exact same problem.in the last 3 years...But i have Uninstalled the google Play Service and tried to install a newer version of it ,but it won't allow any other versions of it to be installed ( even more recent versions as well as the same version) ,There is also 2 versions of google play store running as well ..About to give up on android and go to apple

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Before we conclude that the device is compromised instead of a possible misunderstanding of how the Android system works (or bug), perhaps a screenshot might help clarify the issue. Feel free to [edit] the question to add the screenshot. If you can't upload the screenshot there, post the link to the comment and someone else may edit and incorporated to the question.

Comment: Possibly related: [Multiple numbered copies of com.google.android.gms inside /data/app using up all the space on a device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242921/44325)