# Purge /data/system/packages.xml from manually deleted packages

Tags: android-10, system-apps

I manually deleted around 50 obsolete Trichrome Library packages using `rm` as explained [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242721/can-i-delete-old-trichrome-library-under-data-app/).

Of course doing this brutal `rm` delete thing instead of a more graceful `pm uninstall` leaves all of the old Trichrome versions entries as leftover in `/data/system/packages.xml`.

```
<package name="com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438908633" 
    codePath="/data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438908633-SwvwbO_SyYGt5Xu9yACVFw==" 
    nativeLibraryPath="/data/app/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_438908633-SwvwbO_SyYGt5Xu9yACVFw==/lib" 
    primaryCpuAbi="armeabi-v7a" secondaryCpuAbi="arm64-v8a" publicFlags="0" 
    privateFlags="0" ft="1781fabc898" it="1781fac0a2e" ut="1781fac0a2e" 
    version="438908633" userId="10263" installer="com.android.vending">
```

Is there a way to purge it automatically? Reboot doesn't clean it.

Or can I just edit such xml and remove leftover entries?

[Android 10]

Comment: @beeshyams it is there: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java#632. But most probably it also got converted from plain to binary XML (like AndroidManifest was and) as Android did to other XML files on device to reduce parsing overhead. So it needs to be decoded.

Comment: it's a file not a folder

Comment: Ju Tutt, OK, thanks, but no entries like you mentioned @IrfanLatif it is not coded, I was mistaken in assuming it to be a folder

Comment: @beeshyams at least in AOSP code it's coded in [ABX format](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.0.0_r1/cmds/abx/src/com/android/commands/abx/Abx.java#33).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually edited `packages.xml` deleting relevant sections from `<package name>` to `</package name>` for every obsolete Trichrome package, working fine.

Make sure owner `system` and permissions `rw-rw---- 660` are preserved after edit, then reboot.

For extra safety I first made a backup of the original file and for convenience I edited a copy of the file on a PC using Notepad++, then pushed back on my device.