# how to make Samsung j3 with 8G rom usable

Tags: internal-storage, custom-roms, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-j3

I have a Samsung j3 phone with 8g internal rom, 16g sd card and Android 5.1. It is in excellent condition.

Recently "storage is running out" errors started appearing, and even services stopped working because of this. There is nothing on the phone except the usual Google stuff (maps, googleplay etc).

Photos, videos, etc are of course stored on sd card.

I already disabled all samsung apps (bloatware).

I already configured apps to use sd card when possible (only a few apps offered this and even those store much of their data in internal storage).

Right now I can use the phone only if I empty the caches of applications and switch off networking. As soon as I enable networking, the caches start filling (googleplay, maps, etc) and in a few minutes storage run out.

Is it possible to make it usable with rooting and using a custom ROM? If yes, what ROM should I try?

"Usable" means to me:

- calling,
- texting,
- browser,
- photos,
- some kind of navigation (maps)

Comment: Some users have encountered that Android keeps a lot of [old and outdated stuff internally](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242721/2241). Unfortunately these directories are only accessible on rooted devices. On unrooted devices the only way would be to perform a factory reset. But as apps are getting bigger you may end up again in the same situation. Note that rooting automatically erases all user data thus is equivalent to a factory-reset.

Comment: "*If yes, what ROM should I try?*" you can browse available ROMs on [XDA Devs](https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/samsung-galaxy-j3-2016-roms-kernels-recoveries.6456/), but note that ROM recommendation is off-topic here.